# how to come to try: block from except: block in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
summ=0
average=0
count=0
try:
    while True:
        enterNumber=raw_input("Enter a number:")
        if enterNumber=='done':
            print summ
            print average
            print count
            break
        else:
            summ=summ+int(enterNumber)
            count=count+1
            average=float(summ/count)


except:
    print "Invalid number!" #when this block is reached the program ends,
                            #I want the program to continue till I enter                  
                            #'done'
```

Comment: just add the `try` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Use `while` around `try/except`.

Comment: your `try`, `except` block should only wrap around `int(enterNumber)` (and maybe only catch `ValueError`).

Answer (score 0):

The `try: ... except: ...` block does not control the flow of the program in an arbitrary way - it just ensures the `except` (or the other counterparts like the `else` and `finally` blocks) is run whenever an exceptions occurs.

To "go back" to another part of the program you have to use another contrso stucture. One that could be usefull here is a `while` block

```
while True:
    try:
         # code goes here
         ...
    except:
         # handle exception
         ...
    else:
         # The else block of a `try` is
         # only entered when no exceptions occur
         break  # this gets out of the while block
```

Answer (score 0):

```
summ=0
average=0
count=0
while True:
  # add try/except under while's scope
  try:
    enterNumber=raw_input("Enter a number:")
    if enterNumber=='done':
        print (summ)
        print (average)
        print (count)
        break
    else:
        summ=summ+int(enterNumber)
        count=count+1
        average=float(summ/count)
  except Exception as e:
      print (e)
      print ("Invalid number!") #when this block is reached the program ends,
                              #I want the program to continue till I enter                  
                              #'done'

Enter a number: hey
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hey'
Invalid number!
Enter a number: 10
Enter a number: done
10
10.0
1
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be a version of what you want:

```
enterNumber = None
summ = 0
average = 0
count = 0

while enterNumber != 'done':
    enterNumber = raw_input("Enter a number:")
    try:
        enterInt = int(enterNumber)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number!")
        continue

    summ += enterInt
    count += 1

# average = summ/count        # this works in python 3
average = summ / float(count) # the safe way for python 2
print(summ)
print(average)
print(count)
```

note:

- you need not calculate the average within the input loop.
- `try/catch` only wraps the part of the code that might raise an exception.
- `float(summ/count)` (in your version) does the division in the integers (at least in python 2); `summ / float(count)` may be what you want.
- this code prints `Invalid number!` when you enter `done`. this could be improved.